# Redirect the output of a process to itself as an input during execution using bash

Tags: bash, stream, pipe, stdout, stdin

I have a program which reads from stdin and prints to stdout. I want to be able to redirect output to serve as an input for the program during its execution. I prefer not to use `expect`. Below is an example script using fifo but it's flawed in some way which I am unable to understand.

```
mkfifo fifo
echo "Initial input" > fifo
cat  fifo |  ./my_program > fifo
rm -rf fifo
```

Answer (score 1):

This fails because the `echo` statement will wait forever for a reader to attach.

One alternative is:

```
mkfifo fifo
{ echo "Initial input"; cat fifo; } |  ./my_program > fifo
```

It's up to `./my_program` to:

- Flush its output buffer
- Not exceed the pipe buffers
- Exit at a reachable condition

If the program fails to do any of the above, it will hang or deadlock.  This is a problem with `./my_program` and not with the bash snippet.

Comment: So if the program is single threaded there is no chance to write and read simultaneously, is there ? I mean the moment I write there is no reader consuming the stream so there will be deadlock.

Comment: It just needs to be opened for both reading and writing, and this snippet does both in parallel. Posix only guarantees 4k of buffer space though